# How to remove this horizontal scrollbar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got this irritating horizontal scroll on my bootstrap page. Can't figure out what is making it behave like this or what to do about it?

JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/FatAlbert/cd1syrd9/2/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- navigation-->
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                            <div class="container-fluid">

                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">Meny</button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="xxx" /></a>

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav><!-- / navigation-->
                </div>
            </div><!-- / header-->
        </div><!-- / container-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="first-page-content">
                <div class="container">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-big" src="xx"  />
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, arcu nulla. Maecenas congue, felis leo et, pulvinar sollicitudin lacinia libero rhoncus, nam dolor, velit leo ullamcorper massa. Risus netus facilisis tempus mollis, nullam nibh ridiculus potenti donec pulvinar proin. Sit in ultrices sed orci pellentesque, nunc tempor fusce fusce ultrices felis molestie. Lorem nam pellentesque integer urna nam. 
                        </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/first-content-->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="pull-right">
                Some<br />
                Info<br />
            </p>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /footer-->

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 160px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

p {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-align: justify;
}

a {
    color: #0071BB;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.wrapper {
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 25px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #5FC8FF;
}

.header .glyphicon-wrench {
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.header h4 {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.img-responsive.img-big {
    margin-top: 75px;
}

.navbar {
    border: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #92C7E1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #98CEE5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #98CEE5;
}

a.navbar-brand {
    padding: 5px;
}

.row {
}

.alert {
}

.well {
}

.footer p {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FDFDFB;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .first-page-content p {
        margin: 75px auto 25px auto;
        width: 524px;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment, just add this code in your CSS it will completely disable your horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

As per [Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Therefore, add the class `container` to your `.wrapper` element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnjs2Lq5/)

```
<div class="wrapper container">
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

As for an explanation, the `.row` class has `-15px` margins on each side.

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

The `.container` class effectively displaces that with the following:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

In addition to reading the [Bootstrap 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/), I'd suggest reading the article "[The Subtle Magic Behind Why the Bootstrap 3 Grid Works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)".

Comment: Thanks! You also solved my sticky footer problem which didn't work either.

Comment: In my case, I could not use .container because it has fixed width on smaller devices. I fix this with .container-fluid.

Comment: Thank you very much. There was an overflow because of the horizontal scroll which was getting applied by default. On adding class="container-fluid" it got aligned perfectly.

Comment: It solved the issue. I already had everything inside a div with a container-fluid class, but it seems that the immediate parent of row (a form in my case) must be the one with container-fluid class applied.

Answer (score 17):

Just copy this code to your CSS, it will disable your horizontal scroll bar.

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: This will just hide the browser scroll bar. The .row element will still be out of bounds and you will have problems with most mobile devices.

Answer (score 14):

Writing:

```
html, body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

in your CSS, is a way to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste this in CSS code

```
   html, body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting overflow-x: hidden; works but it will affect **scrolling events**. Putting rows within the container worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is basically caused due to the parent .container is missing. The solution is that you can add a .no-container class to the row and add margin: 0 to compensate the negative margin of the row class.

See the below CSS and HTML markup code:

```css
.no-container {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important; 
}
.row {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--<div class="container"> Container is commented -->
<div class="row no-container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">column-6</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">column-6</div>
</div>
<!--</div> Container ends here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had one **container-fluid class div tag** in another **container-fluid class div tag**. Removing one of them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It works for me.

```
.col-12{
    padding-right: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0!important;
}

.row{
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px; 
}
```