# How to align height of neighboring columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: Required Look]

Here's what, I am currently getting in Bootstrap:
[image: Current Bootstrap Look]

I want to achieve the following:

1. *Width* ratios must be such that `Sites : User : Download = 2:8:2`
2. `Sites-Banner`, `Sites-Search`, `Download-Banner`, `Download-Summary` all should have same *heights*
3. `User-Login` must have combined *height* of `Sites-Banner` & `Sites-Search` (or `Download-Banner` & `Download-Summary`)
4. *Heights* of `Sites-List`, `User-Operations`, `Download-Details` must be independent and can extend as long as required.

Here's my code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L2ru3w5/) (*Check Update 1*)

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-primary">
          <p id="sites-banner">Sites Banner</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-secondary">
          <p id="sites-search">Sites Search</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-success">
          <p id="sites-list">Sites List</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-danger">
          <p id="user-login">User Login</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-warning">
          <p id="user-operations">User Operations</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-info">
          <p id="downloader-banner">Download Banner</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-light">
          <p id="download-summary">Download Summary</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-dark">
          <p id="download-details">Download Details</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. I am not able to align the *height* of `User-Login` with `Sites-Banner` & `Sites-Search` [Done : Update 1]
2. `Sites-List`, `User-Operations` & `Download-Details` do not extend independently

**Update 1:** [New Code](https://jsfiddle.net/nt4pm7g3/)

1. I  got the `User-Login` to have combined height of `Sites-Banner` & `Sites-Search`, by wrapping them in a single `row` (`<div class="row">`)
2. But I am still not able to get the heights of `Sites-List`, `User-Operations`, `Download-Details` to be independent.

**Update 2:** [New Code](https://jsfiddle.net/uda1c8jx/1/)

3. Got the *heights* of `Sites-List`, `User-Operations`, `Download-Details` to be ***look*** independent.
4. But the there's lot of padding in between columns, which introduces white space in between and makes them look not aligned

[image: Bootstrap Update 2 Look]

**Update 3:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdw7r6v9/1/)

Although in Update 2 code it may look like that `Sites-List`, `User-Operations` & `Download Details` have different heights, they actually do not. They look so since we have applied background-color classes only to `div` element that contains the list.

[image: Bootstrap Update 3 Look]

For the issue regarding padding in between columns that can be solved by applying a `mx-0` class attribute on the two rows, to make margin as `0`
Rows have a negative margin of `-15 px` by default.
Checkout: [Bootstrap negative margin on rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282923/bootstrap-negative-margin-on-rows)

Without `mx-0` would cause a horizontal scrollbar on page. Checkout: [Bootstrap columns cause horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202607/bootstrap-columns-cause-horizontal-scrollbar)

Summary:

- Treat `row` & `col` as Table's `tr` and `td`
- Always put content in `col`
- A `col` should necessarily have `row` as parent. Checkout: [Bootstrap Grid Working & Guidlines](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

Comment: Maybe this helps a little https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351404/bootstrap-combining-rows-rowspan

Comment: @ikiK Thanks! Now I understand that I needed to create 2 rows. Plz check the update, since I'm not able to get the heights of cols in row2 to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.col p{
  margin: 0;
}

.user-login{
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Downloader</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-primary">
            <p>Sites-Banner</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-secondary">
            <p>Sites-Search</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-danger user-login">
            <p>User-Login</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">

          <div class="bg-info">
            <p>Download-Banner</p>
          </div>
            <div class="bg-light">
              <p>Download-Summary</p>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-success">
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
            <p>Sites-List</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-warning">
            <p>User-Operations</p>
            <p>User-Operations</p>
            <p>User-Operations</p>
            <p>User-Operations</p>
            <p>User-Operations</p>
            <p>User-Operations</p>
            <p>User-Operations</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->
        <div class="col">
          <div class="bg-dark">
            <p>Download-Details</p>
            <p>Download-Details</p>
            <p>Download-Details</p>
            <p>Download-Details</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand that I needed to create 2 rows. Plz check the update, since I'm not able to get the heights of cols in row2 to be independent.

Comment: Please check my updated code. Do you want this to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna accept your answer since it resolved both of my issues. But in the updated code, there's lot of padding in between columns, which introduces white space and makes them look not aligned. Is there anyway resolve that?