# Scroll bar appearing on at the bottom of bootstrap built webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a page and cannot understand why there is a bottom nav scroll bar appears. The Auda website https://www.audatex.co.in/ It appears that some element is off screen but I cannot understand what! Solution welcome! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share code instead of simply a link to your website. Links vanish and this question would then become pointless. Temporary solution, add this to your body tag in your css stylesheet `overflow-x: hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having it's because of the `margin` you're giving to `.row` class

```
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Remove it or even fix it and problem solved.

Comment: This is bootstrap's css. Can u sure override it?

Answer (score 1):

SOLERA STATISTICS Section is creating the horizontal scroll bar.
Update your bootstrap css file. Or use the following css:

```
.container-fluid{
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You remove class `row` in this html code

```
<section class="stats-section" id="solera">
  <div class="container-fluid wow fadeInDown delay-05 animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
    <!--main-section-start-->
    <h2> Solera Statistics</h2>
    <div class=""> //Remove class `row` in there
    ...
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Suggestion: If you want to keep the row class for whatever reason, put the row in a contianer-fluid div. For an explanation check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758457/how-to-remove-this-horizontal-scrollbar-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

The `#solera .row` element is wider than the page.

Consider adding the following to your css:

```
#solera .row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set margin 0

```
#solera .row{
     margin:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement css class and assign it to appropriate division: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: This just hides the problem, it doesn't fix it.

Comment: You should change your answer and link that answer. Adding the class `container` to the container the `.row` is in is the best solution imo.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `animate.css` the scroll appear. use overflow-x:hidden; in body.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap.css is missing styles for `container-fluid`. 
Use a stable version of bootstrap CSS. Currently you are using Bootstrap v3.0.3. Use Bootstrap (v3.3.7)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The 2.x .container-fluid was replaced by .container in Bootstrap 3.*

**But, for Bootstrap 3.1**

`container-fluid` has returned again in Bootstrap 3.1. Now container-fluid can be used to create a full width layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your html body will overflowing. you need to hide the overflow on x-axis. use bellow code it will help you

```
body{

overflow-x:hidden;

}
```